# Combing hair extends it

Tags: particles

OK so I'm trying to make a feather by using scaled cube as a base, and i use 2 edges as a vertex group for particles, now when i try to comb it it either rises towards me or on the very top when I try to comb it - it extends ridiculously (see images)

after some combing here i already had to cut off top because it went too much
[image]

after I try to fix the top a little bit 
[image]

keep lenghts and root are checked, any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to apply scale in Object mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Scale*).

The hair length will be affected and probably all the combing already done will be damaged, so I'd suggest starting with a fresh particle system after applying scale.

Comment: Oh yes, that was an issue I forgot I asked this here otherwise I would answer it.